# Inner Join query shows error in spring boot but the same query gives the result in mysql workbench

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

When I use Inner join in Spring Boot, I get an `InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException` but an equivalent query works in MySQL Workbench.

This is the query which runs successfully in MySQL Workbench:

```sql
select gstem.orders.id,gstem.orders.order_no,gstem.orders.date, gstem.orders.quantity,gstem.orders.weight,
gstem.orders.eta_date, gstem.statuses_types.name as status, gstem.customers.company_name from gstem.orders inner join gstem.statuses_types on gstem.orders.status_id = gstem.statuses_types.id inner join gstem.customers on gstem.orders.customer_id = customers.id where gstem.statuses_types.category = "order_status" and statuses_types.name = "Received" and stage = "order" order by order_no;
```

And this query fails in Spring Boot:

```sql
Select `orders`.`id`, `order_no`, `date`, `quantity`, `weight`, `amount`, `eta_date`, `statuses_types`.`name` as `status`, `customers`.`company_name` from `orders` inner join `statuses_types` on `orders`.`status_id` = `statuses_types`.`id` inner join `customers` on `orders`.`customer_id` = `customers`.`id` where     `statuses_types`.`category` = :category and `stage` = :stage order by `order_no` "
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Failed to complete request: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Unable to find column position by name: `amount` [Column 'amount' not found.] [n/a]; SQL [n/a]
2023-03-10T13:58:58.783+05:30 ERROR 23388 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet] : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Unable to find column position by name: `amount` [Column 'amount' not found.] [n/a]; SQL [n/a]] with root cause
```

Comment: How did you write the method in java?

Answer (score 1):

You don't hava colum `amount`.
Just read error: Unable to find column position by name: `amount` [Column 'amount' not found.]

Comment: How should he solve it?

Answer (score -1):

Its because in the query below 'amount' is an extra column